# delayed Angular spinner without flickering

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, spinner, angular-http-interceptors

At the moment I'm trying to use the Angular HttpInterceptor to show a spinner *once*, so it doesnt flicker everytime a HttpRequest is done. My currect code for the interceptor.service.ts looks like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private spinnerService: SpinnerService) {}

  showSpinner() {
    this.spinnerService.show.next(true);
    console.log('true');
  }

  hideSpinner() {
    this.spinnerService.show.next(false);
    console.log('false');
  }

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler,
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const responseTimer$ = next
      .handle(req)
      .pipe(filter(e => e instanceof HttpResponse));
    timer(300)
      .pipe(takeUntil(responseTimer$))
      .subscribe(() => this.showSpinner());

    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      tap(evt => {
        if (evt instanceof HttpResponse) {
          this.hideSpinner();
        }
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

But if i try this code, the console says:

```
interceptor.service.ts:20 true
interceptor.service.ts:25 false
4 x interceptor.service.ts:20 true
4 x interceptor.service.ts:25 false
5 x interceptor.service.ts:25 false
interceptor.service.ts:25 false
```

But in my opinion it should be x times true and at the end false. I hope you understand what i'm trying to archieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to create your own `Subject` that will track how many requests have been made, and then safeguard yourself from mistakes by throwing an error if the tracking count goes below zero.

```js
class BusySubject extends Subject<number> {
    private _previous: number = 0;

    public next(value: number) {
        this._previous += value;
        if (this._previous < 0) {
            throw new Error('unexpected negative value');
        }
        return super.next(this._previous);
    }
}
```

The above is a subject that will sum the values overtime with a safety check for below zero.

You can then use this in an interceptor

```js
@Injectable()
export class BusyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    private _requests: BusySubject = new BusySubject();

    public get busy(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this._requests.pipe(
            map((requests: number) => Boolean(requests)),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
        );
    }

    public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        this._requests.next(1);
        return next.handle(req).pipe(finalize(() => this._requests.next(-1)));
    }
}
```

It's important to noticed in the above that I use `distinctUntilChanged()` for the busy indicator, and also use `finalize()` for the decrease trigger. These are important to track the proper state of being busy.

The above *should work* no matter *when* you subscribe to busy. Since the `_previous` value is an internal state of the subject. It should continue to track correctly even if nothing is subscribed. It works kind of like a `BehaviorSubject()` except that it's using a `+=` to apply the changes.

Comment: FYI: I replaced my interceptor service with your interceptor. After that i just added `this.busy.subscribe(b => this.spinnerService.show.next(b));
`to the service and it worked like a charm. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 2):

You will need a counter in your interceptor service, which shows the number of pending requests. You show your spinner when the number is >0.

---

**Edit:**

Just theory from text editor

```
@Injectable()
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  pendingCount$: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(0);

  constructor(private spinnerService: SpinnerService) {
    this.pendingCount$.pipe(
      map(Boolean),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
    ).subscribe(
      show => this.spinnerService.show.next(show),
    );
  }

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler,
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  
    this.pendingCount$.next(this.pendingCount$.value + 1);

    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      tap(evt => this.pendingCount$.next(this.pendingCount$.value - 1)),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. It's simple, but effective.

Comment: That sounds like a good solution. Could you provide the information where/how i would implement a counter of the pending requests in this code?

Comment: You can store that information in the interceptor, since it is a singleton service

Comment: But when do i have to increment/decrement the counter? I also noticed, that the ```takeUntil(responseTimer$)```doubles the OPTIONS-Request. So if i do not comment that line out, my backend thinks it was called with the same request a second time.

Comment: You can filter the options method. You increment and decrement where you show and hide the spinner right now

Comment: But how and where would i filter that?
And how do i show the spinner if the number is >0? Should i use an observable for that how exactly do you mean that?
I would really appreciate some example code how i would fix my code and doesnt double the OPTIONS-request.

Comment: I added some code I theory-coded in text editor. I don't think the option request needs to be filtered after all, it is also a request which responses at some point

Comment: This will get **stuck** when the next handler throws an error.

Comment: The problem regarding the option-request was, that there were two .handle() methods.With your code, this problem was solved.

But the spinner doesn't hide with your code, because the counter will stay negativ at the end.